# Update a record in table whose associated values in another table has a particular value

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have a table, A, that has a 1-* relationship with records in table B (i.e. there can be multiple records in B that correspond to a single record in A).

Table A looks like this

| ID | Header_Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |

Table B looks like

| ID | Line_Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | D |
| 1 | E |
| 2 | D |
| 2 | D |

I want the header status in Table A to be updated to **"G"** for those records whose all the associated line status is 'D'.

For the above example, it should update second row (i.e. record with ID - 2 ) in Table A as both the records associated with it in Table B has the status as 'D' .
It shouldn't update the first record (i.e. record with ID - 1 ) as it has one of the associated records in Table B with status 'E'.

I was trying this query

```
UPDATE A a 
INNER JOIN B b ON a.id = b.id 
SET a.header_status = 'G' 
where b.line_status = 'D';
```

It is not updating any rows. What can I try next?

Comment: Strings need to be quoted - G and D are not valid in your update because they aren't quoted. But you also need to check that all rows for and id  have a value of 'D'

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using an update join, we can try:

```sql
UPDATE TableA a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM TableB
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING MIN(Line_Status) = MAX(Line_Status) AND
           MIN(Line_Status) = 'D'
) b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
SET
    a.Header_Status = 'G';
```

The subquery aliased as `b` finds all `ID` values from the B table for which all line status values are `D` only.  The join then restricts the A table to only these `ID` records, and then we update these records' header status to `G`.

Comment: The record in Table A should be updated only when all the associated records in Table B has the status 'D'. If any one of the record doesn't have the status as 'D' then it should not update the record in Table A.

Comment: Please check the updated answer, your question was not entirely clear to me until you explained in the comment above.

Comment: How this Min and Max is working with string values ? Will this query work fine if  the status values are integers?

Comment: Yes, the logic should work with either strings or numbers.  The `HAVING` clause is simply asserting that a given `ID` have only one line status, and that this one value is `D`.